# Can't submit app for login review

Tags: facebook

We've filled out the forms, but we can't submit the app for review. I get this error

Currently Ineligible for Submission
Before you can submit your app detail page you must first comply with App Center Guidelines. Please make sure you have specified how your app integrates with Facebook and have met all the requirements. Click here to update your integration.

And there is a red circle next to the "App Info" section, but the rest of the sections of the App Details don't show any errors. The App Info section is complete.

The app has been working for over a year, we are trying to get it confirmed for Graph 2.0. We think we are ok, but I can't figure out how to submit it for review.

Comment: If you are submitting App Details you need to choose at least one platform under App Center Listed Platforms

Comment: Can you provide your app ID as well as a screenshot for where you're seeing the error?